# Heroku giving me 500 | server error on my hosted laravel web application

Tags: laravel, heroku

I've just deployed an app and am getting the following: when i try to login or register while its working well on my local host
" Error: 500 | SERVER ERROR. "
http://blooming-gorge-99995.herokuapp.com/register

Comment: A 500 error means somewhere in your logs is a *useful* error message.

Comment: @KamleshPaul That should certainly be fixed, but it won't cause a 500 error.

Comment: tried everything and puting on mysql add on on heroku. but still same error.

Comment: You still need to look in the logs for *what the error message says*.